# How to find out the computational complexity of a algorithm using GuessCompx package

Tags: r, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have been trying to assess the computational complexity of Roughkmeans_PE algorithm found in the `Softclustering` package. To assess the computational complexity of a algorithm, `GuessCompx` package is available from the CRAN site. When I tried to assess the complexity, it works well only when we use the example code as given below.

```
CompEst(d = ggplot2::diamonds[, 5:10], f = dist, replicates = 10, max.time = 10)
```

But if I try to assess the complexity of Roughkmeans_PE, I get the following error message;

**The code that I used:**

```
library(SoftClustering)
CompEst(iris[,-5], RoughKMeans_PE, random.sampling = FALSE, max.time = 30, start.size = NULL, replicates = 4, strata = NULL, power.factor = 2, alpha.value = 0.005, plot.result = TRUE)
```

**The error I got:**

> Error in if (datatypeInteger(meansMatrix)) { :    missing value where
>   TRUE/FALSE needed Timing stopped at: 0.01 0 0.02

I request you to please clarify how can I find out the complexity of my own algorithm using the  GuessCompx package.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of the `GuessCompx` package. The error you see actually comes from the clustering function for which you need to input some mandatory arguments (the documentation is not clear about that)

```
RoughKMeans_PE(iris[, -5])                                   # gives the same error
RoughKMeans_PE(iris[, -5], meansMatrix = 1, nClusters = 3)   # OK
```

That's why the `CompEst()` function gives the error, you need to wrap your clustering function with the correct arguments inside an anonymous or custom function; this will work:

```
f = function(df) RoughKMeans_PE(df, 1, 2, 100)
CompEst(iris[, -5], f)
```

However, it won't give your the right result, first because the dataset **iris** is too small to measure any time difference, and second because the computation time of your clustering algorithm has a high variability (number of iterations). So I suggest you change the default arguments, increasing `replicates` and `max.time`. Resulting plot on a larger dataset seems to give **O(N)** or **O(NLOGN)** asymptotic behavior:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The answers you have given here is helpful. Now I am able to find out complexity of my algorithm. However, when I run the code more than one time, it gives me different results each time. for example, the time complexity at first is linear, and it is quadratic for second time, same is in the case of memory complexity. is there any way to arrive at definite values, I mean, if I run the code multiple times, it should say the same results. i.e., if it says 'linear complexity' at first run, it should be 'linear complexity' for any number of runs. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. As I said, in such case where the algorithm has high variability, you must choose bigger dataset (>10 000 rows) increase the number of replicates (maybe go up to 20) and the max.time argument (like 3 minutes = 180) maybe. This will stabilize the outpout (in my case is stabilized to NLOGN complexity for time and LOG for memory).

Comment: you could also study the "worst case complexity" that could be a different complexity function, by fitting with only the higher points of each resample (in X axis) see picture (i updated the picture)